# Unable to read text from a word doc in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I have exhausted my search options on this. I have a 'picked' file in a UWP app (C#) Storagefolder. I need to be able to read the text into a string from this doc.

Has anyone done this, as yet, I have not been able to find a working code sample?

Comment: This is code so far to get text:

Comment: It would help if you could update your questions with what have you tried so far, it will be easier for people to recommend solutions.

Comment: How do I send code as you said not to put in comments??

Comment: Click `Edit` under your question.

Comment: Plus format that code as such: highlight and use the `{ }` button

Answer (score 1):

Word documents aren't like regular text files, so the built-in storage apis can't just read the text for you.

You can use the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-Sdk) to do this, it supports UWP.

There are some examples on MSDN for different [Word Document Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc850833.aspx) like [opening and reading text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx), but you'll need to follow the UWP pattern, similar to [this example for Excel](https://pauliom.com/2015/06/25/read-and-edit-openxml-docs-word-excel-etc-in-windows-10-with-c/).

There's also a commercial library available with [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/uwp).